# Display regional characters

Tags: c++, visual-c++, regional-settings

I need to show some regional characters in window:

MessageBoxW(NULL, L"ąčęėįšųūž ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽ", L"hello!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

Progrmm runes fine if I set default locale of this region. But how to deal when default locale is for example  English UK? In this case I see only "?" instead of regional chars in shown `MessageBox`. I build application using Visual C++ and run under Windows 8.1 OS.

Comment: can you explain better how to reproduce the unexpected result you have? For example, are you talking about the appearance of the characters in Visual Studio when you compile the file or the message that appears when you run the program?

Comment: I'm talking about message that appears when I run the program

Comment: It is Unicode, not affected by locale at all.  At most you might have a font problem, not being able to display a glyph.  You'd then see a rectangle, not a question mark.  Only reasonable explanation is that your text editor cannot handle these characters.  Be sure to save the file as UTF8 with a BOM.

Comment: then edit your question to clarify this, otherwise you will get a lot of confusing answers. @HansPassant too got it wrong as you can see. Also add info about the operating system and version in which you tested it.